# how to check odbc version on linux or how to check is there odbc driver install or not

Tags: linux

I am trying to install odbc driver on linux but  could not check either it's install or not , please tell me how to check odbc driver are install on linux

Answer (score 3):

Both Debian and Redhat/CentOS have a config file that lists all the ODBC drivers you have installed on the system.

> /etc/odbcinst.ini

```
[PostgreSQL]
Description=ODBC for PostgreSQL
Driver=/usr/lib/psqlodbcw.so
Setup=/usr/lib/libodbcpsqlS.so
Driver64=/usr/lib64/psqlodbcw.so
Setup64=/usr/lib64/libodbcpsqlS.so
FileUsage=1

[MySQL]
Description=ODBC for MySQL
Driver=/usr/lib/libmyodbc5.so
Setup=/usr/lib/libodbcmyS.so
Driver64=/usr/lib64/libmyodbc5.so
Setup64=/usr/lib64/libodbcmyS.so
FileUsage=1

[MariaDB ODBC Driver]
Description=MariaDB Connector/ODBC v.3.1
Driver=/usr/lib64/libmaodbc.so
UsageCount=1
```

Answer (score 3):

There are two open source ODBC driver managers for UNIX (unixODBC and iODBC). unixODBC Driver Manager as it is the one included with most Linux distributions and some UNIX distributions.

In unixODBC ODBC drivers are defined in the odbcinst.ini file. If unixODBC is already installed you can use unixODBC's odbcinst program to locate the odbcinst.ini file used to defined drivers:

```
$ odbcinst -j
unixODBC 2.2.11
DRIVERS............: /etc/odbcinst.ini
SYSTEM DATA SOURCES: /etc/odbc.ini
USER DATA SOURCES..: /root/.odbc.ini
```

Note, the above command also shows the version of unixODBC, in this case version 2.2.11.